# Create an array from another array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, nested

I need some help. I have a 1-D array with the following information:

```
1, 17, 2, 18, 3, 19, 1, 17, 2, 18, 3, 19, 1, 17, 2, 18, 3, 19, 1, 17, 2, 18, 3, 19
```

As you can see, there are total of 24 elements in the array. Now,first two elements, (1, 17) can be considered a pair so basically we have pair of `(1, 17), (2, 18), (3, 19)` in one Block. And we have total 4 blocks giving the array above.

Now, I have to arrange the array in such a way that its elements are in this order:

```
1, 17, 1, 17, 1, 17, 1, 17, 2, 18, 2, 18, 2, 18, 2, 18, 3, 19, 3, 19, 3, 19, 3, 19.
```

As you can see, I have to pick first pair, insert it 4 times (4 is the # of blocks that we have) and then go onto the next pair `(2, 18)`, insert it 4 times and continue..

Now # of blocks and # of pairs can be dynamic. For example, if I have 3 blocks and 4 pairs ,

Original array will be like this:

```
1, 17, 2, 18, 3, 19, 4, 20  1, 17, 2, 18, 3, 19, 4, 20, 1, 17, 2, 18, 3, 19, 4, 20
```

And the desired array will be like this:

```
1, 17, 1, 17, 1, 17, 2, 18, 2, 18, 2, 18, 3, 19, 3, 19, 3, 19, 4, 20, 4, 20, 4, 20.
```

Another example,

If I have two blocks and five pairs:

Original array will be:

```
1, 17, 2, 18, 3, 19, 4, 20, 5, 21, 1, 17, 2, 18, 3, 19, 4, 20, 5, 21,
```

Desired array will be:

```
1, 17, 1, 17, 2, 18, 2, 18, 3, 19, 3, 19, 4, 20, 4, 20, 5, 21, 5, 21.
```

Can anyone help me with this.? I will really appreciate it.

Comment: I think you should make_pair for each two elements, insert them into a vector and then sort it according to first element of each pair. alternatively just insert pairs (of each two elements) into a multimap

Comment: We're not an algorithm generator!

Comment: `std::sort` on `std::pair`...

Answer (score 0):

Hacky version which may help:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int array[] = {1, 17, 2, 18, 3, 19, 1, 17, 2, 18, 3, 19, 1, 17, 2, 18, 3, 19, 1, 17, 2, 18, 3, 19};
    typedef std::pair<int, int> (p_t)[sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]) / 2];
    p_t &p = reinterpret_cast<p_t&>(array);

    std::sort(std::begin(p), std::end(p));

    for (auto i : array) {
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```